# Python/django LDAP authentication fails with invalid requirement

Tags: python, django, ldap

I have a problem with implementing ldap in ralph3 application written in python/django. I've installed all the prerequisities and successfully connected to ldap server with

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://10.202.206.30 -b dc=bod,dc=local -x
```

but when I try to follow the steps in [this official tutorial](http://ralph-ng.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation/configuration/) and create prod_ldap.txt (template):

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://activedirectory.domain:389"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "secret"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "secret"
AUTH_LDAP_PROTOCOL_VERSION = 3
AUTH_LDAP_USER_USERNAME_ATTR = "sAMAccountName"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH_BASE = "DC=allegrogroup,DC=internal"
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH_FILTER = '(&(objectClass=*)({0}=%(user)s))'.format(
AUTH_LDAP_USER_USERNAME_ATTR)
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch(AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH_BASE,
ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH_FILTER)
AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
"first_name": "givenName",
"last_name": "sn",
"email": "mail",
"company": "company",
"manager": "manager",
"department": "department",
"employee_id": "employeeID",
"location": "officeName",
"country": "ISO-country-code",
}
```

and try to install it with pip:

```
root@ubuntur:/home/marcel/ralph3# pip install -r requirements/prod_ldap.txt:
```

I get this error:

```
Invalid requirement: 'import ldap'
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 
82, in __init__
req = Requirement(req)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-
packages/pip/_vendor/packaging/requirements.py", line 96, in __init__
requirement_string[e.loc:e.loc + 8]))
InvalidRequirement: Invalid requirement, parse error at "u'ldap'"
```

I also tried to delete all the lines in prod_ldap.txt except these two:

```
import ldap
from django_auth_ldap.config import LDAPSearch, GroupOfNamesType
```

and the error was the same, so I think the problem is with the import of ldap, not with the settings.

OS is Ubuntu 14.04 64 as requested by creator of application.

Thank you.

Comment: prod_ldap.txt should include the requirements,but not python code. refer to the github repository https://github.com/allegro/ralph/blob/ng/requirements/prod_ldap.txt

Comment: Could you please create an answer? It really helped and got me a lot further to another nifty error message :)